# How to ignore semantic issues on Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator

I dont want to see semantic issues anymore. There are lots of them. Does anyone know how i figure out this problem?

[headache semantic issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOkCE.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm sure you'd love to get an answer to your question, and the best way to do that is to make sure your question is answerable. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then come back and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You're sure to get more help that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uncheck some options in Tools > Options > Text Editor > Display.

Try unchecking the line annotations option:

[image]